# How did Madara get rid of Sasuke's Amaterasu?

Tags: naruto

Just as soon as Madara was revived, Sasuke used Amaterasu on him, and from the scans, it seemed that his armor and his hair was caught in it. But, the next scans showed that the black flames faded away.

How was he able to do this? He did not have rinnegan to suggest that he absorbed it. If so, how was he able to escape?

Answer (score 5):

It's because of two things:

1. Madara is still able to absorb Ninjutsu, even without his eyes. Madara has shown this ability several times (Most notably, by absorbing Hashirama's Senjutsu chakra). Madara was shown to use other eye techniques without eyes, such as the Susano'o. So we can assume that those techniques are sort of "awakened" and can be used even without the original requirements.

   [image]
2. Madara threw his armor away, which was where most of the fire concentrated. The rest was absorbed by his Preta Path ability.

Comment: But i thought he was able to absorb hashirama's chakra because he has his(hashi's) DNA/cells inside him so its like he's got a clone of hashirama inside his body...

Comment: @Aneeshmg: He also absorbed someone's Kyuubi's chakra (the one that was handed out by Naruto) towards the end of the chapter.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha You should just post the picture where Hashirama explicitly said that you absorbed it Ch 657 p2. This is also why Naruto told Sasuke to stop using random jutsus on him.